# Multiple cloud-sql table export as csv

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to export multiple SQL tables as csv by issuing specific queries from cloud-sql.

Below is the code i currently have. When I call the exportTables for multiple tables back to back, I see a 409 error. It's probably becaause cloud-sql instance is busy with an export and it's not allowing subsequent export request.

How can I get this to work ? What would be the ideal solution here.

```
  private void exportTables(String table_name, String query)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
PostMethod httppost =
    new PostMethod(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/"
            + "abc"
            + "/instances/"
            + "zxy"
            + "/export");

String destination_bucket =
    String.join(
        "/",
        "gs://" + "test",
        table_name,
        DateTimeUtil.getCurrentDate() + ".csv");

GoogleCredentials credentials =
    GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(SQLAdminScopes.all());
AccessToken access_token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
access_token.getTokenValue();
httppost.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httppost.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token.getTokenValue());
String request =
    "{"
        + "  \"exportContext\": {"
        + "    \"fileType\": \"CSV\","
        + "    \"uri\":\""
        + destination_bucket
        + "\","
        + "    \"databases\": [\""
        + "xyz"
        + "\"],"
        + "    \"csvExportOptions\": {"
        + "      \"selectQuery\": \""
        + query
        + "\""
        + "    }\n"
        + "  }"
        + "}";
httppost.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(request, "application/json", "UTF-8"));

httpclient.executeMethod(httppost);
if (httppost.getStatusCode() > 200) {
  String response = new String(httppost.getResponseBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  if (httppost.getStatusCode() != 409) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
        "Exception occurred while exporting the table: " + table_name + " Error " + response);
  } else {
    throw new IOException("SQL instance seems to be busy at the moment. Please retry");
  }
}
httppost.releaseConnection();
logger.info("Finished exporting table {} to {}", table_name, destination_bucket);
```

}

Comment: Do you want to run several exports in sequence, right? And when you have 2 in the same time, you have a conflict (409), correct? Did you try to add the `offload: true` value to the `exportContext` object in the request body? Does it solve the issue?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I haven't tried that. Let me try adding this.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere ```offload:true``` did not work for me

Comment: Do you mean still the same 409 error? And you want to run several exports in sequence, right?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere. Yes I got the same error. 
And yea I want to run several exports in sequence.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere ANy other suggestions ?

Comment: Running export blocks other operations on the instance and this is expected behavior. You can either come up with your own script and check for export state and queue a new one when previous is done or try Guilllaume's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have suggestion to fix the issue on Cloud SQL directly, but a solution to execute in sequence the export thanks to a new tool: [Workflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs)

- Define the data format that you want, in JSON, to define ONE export.
- Then provide an array of configuration to your workflow
- In this workflow,

  - Make a loops on the configuration array
  - Perform an API call to Cloud SQL to generate the export on each configuration
  - Get the answer of the API Call, you have the jobId
  - Sleep a while
  - Check if the export is over (with the jobId).

    - If not, sleep and check again
    - If yes, loop (and thus start the next export)

It's serverless and the free tier makes this use case free.